# Cloud Run Jobs - End Time in the past : Jan 20, 1970

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Has anyone ever encountered this problem where the cloud run job creation date time is OK but the End time is in the past (Jan 20, 1970) ?

[image]

And the execution details:

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting past dates. Can you share screenshot? Is it happening with all jobs? How often it is happening?

Comment: Just edited the post with the print screens. It happens for all jobs and randomly

Comment: I don't know if there is any relationship, but a feature has been released in GA this week on Cloud Run Jobs. Maybe a side effect of this roll out? Did it occur once?

Comment: No, it occurred multiple times between yesterday 4 PM UTC and today +- 4 AM. I'm currently monitoring it to see if it happens again, very strange behavior.

Comment: I started getting this recently too.  I thought it was a bug related to me adding a `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`, but maybe the timing is coincidental.

Comment: @Hélder Portela, Have you managed to raise bug bug in Public issue tracker as I suggested in Answer below? If so, can you share the link so that anyone facing issue add their concers too.

Comment: @RoopaM , I have tried to, but it seems that I don't have access to do it, anyway, the problem only happened in the time frame mentioned, I'm not getting it now, do you ?

Comment: @RoopaM, with a little more investigation I found this :

https://issuetracker.google.com/309382596 Cloud Run Job: Start and End Timestamp is 1970

Comment: @HélderPortela Thanks for checking and mentioning the issue tracker. I have updated my answer with the latest update on this issue. So that it will help you and the community. Feel free to update my answer if anything is missing

Answer (score 0):

After monitoring for several times, I also observed the same date. Also I believe this is affecting most of the cloud run users. This might be   a bug in Google cloud console. I suggest you raise a bug report in [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) so that it will bring attention to the engineering team and be resolved soon.

## Update

As per the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/309382596#comment3), the product engineering team is already aware of the issue, and a fix has been implemented. The fix will be applied for future Cloud Run jobs executions.